# Affectiva-JS: out of memory exception after multiple reloads

Tags: javascript, firefox, affdex-sdk

There are two errors happening while using the affektiva js sdk.

First error raised is the "out of memory" exception that occurs within the affectiva library in the affdex-worker.js file at

```
importScripts(url + "affdex-native-bindings.js");
```

The second error subsequently throws a "could not clone object" error while trying to process

```
 catch(err) {
    postMessage({ "message": "ready", "status": false, "detail": err });
  }
```

as both are in the same function, i assume they are conncected.

This error only happens after multiple reloads of the website!

Do I need to manually dispose something on reload?

I tried to include

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
if(detector != null){
        detector.stop();
}
```

});

in the website, but that didnt change things...